# NodeJs login form with SQL Server user auth

Tags: node.js, sql-server

I am having an issue with authenticating users using a SQL Server database. I have established the connection with the database and can pull user from the database. However when trying to query the database for authentication I get an "unhandledpromise - connection is closed" error.

**app.js file:**

```
var sql = require("mssql");
var express = require("express");
var session = require("express-session");
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
var path = require("path");


var dbconfig = {
  server: "Server",
  database: "Test",
  user: "########",
  password: "####################",
  port: 1433,
  options : {
    encrypt: false
  }
};

var app = express();
app.use(session({
  secret: 'Secret',
  resave: true,
  saveUninitalized: true

}));

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: true
}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.get('/', function(request, response) {
  response.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/login.html'));
});

app.post('/auth', function(request, response) {
      var username = request.body.username;
      var password = request.body.password;
      var conn = new sql.ConnectionPool(dbconfig);
      var req = new sql.Request(conn);
      if (username && password) {
        conn.connect();
        req.query('Select * from Admin where username = ? and password = ?', [username, password], function(error, results, fields) {
            if (results.length > 0) {
              request.session.loggedin = true;
              resquest.session.username = username;
              response.redirect('/home');
            } else {
              response.send('Username and/or Password not found');
            }
            conn.close();
            response.end();
          });

        } else{
          response.send('Please enter Username and Password');
        }

      });

      app.get('/home', function(request, response){
        if(request.session.loggedin){
          response.send('Welcome back,' + request.session.username + '!');

        }else{
          response.send('Please sign');
        }
        response.end();
      });
      app.listen(3000);
      function getEMP() {
        var conn = new sql.ConnectionPool(dbconfig);
        var req = new sql.Request(conn);

        conn.connect(function(err) {
          if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            return;
          }
          req.query("Select * from Admin", function(err, recordset) {
            if (err) {
              console.log(err)
            } else {
              console.log(recordset)
            }
            conn.close();
          });
        });
      }

      getEMP();
```

The `getEMP` function returns all of the admins from the database as expected. This is why I am positive the connection is working. This function was used for testing connection.

**Error**

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ConnectionError: Connection is closed.
>   at Request._query (///nodeconSQL/node_modules/mssql/lib/base/request.js:447:37)
>   at Request._query (///nodeconSQL/node_modules/mssql/lib/tedious/request.js:346:11)
>   at shared.Promise (///nodeconSQL/node_modules/mssql/lib/base/request.js:413:12)
>   at new Promise ()
>   at Request.query (///nodeconSQL/node_modules/mssql/lib/base/request.js:412:12)
>   at /home/devops-01/nodeconSQL/app.js:43:13
>   at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (///nodeconSQL/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
>   at next (///nodeconSQL/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
>   at Route.dispatch (///nodeconSQL/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
>   at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (///nodeconSQL/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)

Comment: Would help if you posted exact error message, and if you've debugged, exactly where the error is occurring.

Comment: Edited the question to include error

Answer (score 0):

Your function `getEMP()` uses the callback from `conn.connect()` in order to wait until the connection is established before trying to execute the query.

The function that tries to login executes the query immediately after attempting to open the connection, however since the connection takes some time to be established, this is why you get the error that your connection is not open.

Put your login query inside the `conn.connect(function(err){ /* login code */ })` construct like it is in your `getEMP()` function. You will then need to make sure that you can access the request and response objects in the callback function, for example by using [.bind()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) on your callback function to put the request and response objects into the `this` object. Another option is to use closure functions to get data to the callbacks.

**Example using closures:**

```js
app.post('/auth', function(request, response) {
    var username = request.body.username;
    var password = request.body.password;

    if (username && password) {
        var conn = new sql.ConnectionPool(dbconfig);
        conn.connect((function(){
            var thisConn = conn;
            var req = new sql.Request(thisConn);

            return function(){ //connect callback
            req.query('Select * from Admin where username = ? and password = ?', [username, password], 
            (function(){
                var req = request;
                var resp = response;
                var conn = thisConn;

                return function(error, results, fields) { // query callback
                    if (results.length > 0) {
                        req.session.loggedin = true;
                        req.session.username = username;
                        resp.redirect('/home');
                    } else {
                        response.send('Username and/or Password not found');
                    }
                    conn.close();
                    resp.end();
                };
            })());
            };
        })());
    } else {
      response.send('Please enter Username and Password');
    }
});
```

**Example using bind:**

```js
...

// Inside your /auth route
// make an object with the data our callback needs, to use with .bind()
var callbackData = {"conn": conn, "request": request, "response": response};
var connectCallback = function(err){
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return;
     }
    req.query('Select * from Admin where username = ? and password = ?',
        [username, password], function(error, results, fields) {
        // 2nd level of callback, query callback
        if (results.length > 0) {
              this.request.session.loggedin = true;
              this.resquest.session.username = username;
              this.response.redirect('/home');
        } else {
              this.response.send('Username and/or Password not found');
        }
        this.conn.close();
        this.response.end();
    }.bind(this)); // pass our 'this' object through to the next level
}.bind(callbackData);

conn.connect(connectCallback);
...
```

Comment: I tried your solution and was met with the same error(forced cache clean to be sure). I added callbackData and my Callback just under my req variable.

Comment: @SomeGuyWithaPC Sorry I missed putting the callback into the connect function like I said to do in my explanation. I updated the code in my answer if you want to try it again. Note the `callbackData` being passed through 2 levels of callbacks with `.bind()` now

Comment: @SomeGuyWithaPC there are other ways to do it without bind look at this https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/javascript-callbacks-variable-scope-problem

Comment: are there any nuances I should know about? I am receiving an 'invalid syntax error near ?' error. I updated the syntax to include double quotes and was met with the same error.